# Efficient Serializing of Recursive Data Structures in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am currently working with some large Trie structures in Haskell that I build from a binary file.  The process takes some time, and I was curious if there is a general-case approach to fast-ish (de)serialization of recursive data structures.  For large files and large Tries, using the Show and Read classes is (much) slower than building the tries from scratch.  Perhaps I'm doing it wrong.

The Trie is shaped like this:

```
type Trie e a = T e [Trie e a]
```

What are some good approaches to serializing a recursive structure like this?  Also, what are some good approaches to this problem in general?

Comment: Did you tried [`binary`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary) (binary serialization library) or [`aeson`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson) (blazing fast JSON library)?

Comment: I am familiar with those libraries, yes.  I've used Binary before on other things.  Though it doesn't address the problem in the general case, and that's sort of the crux of my question.

Comment: `Show/Read` _is_ quite slow, and should be expected to be so. Why do you say `binary` doesn't address the problem in general case? Do you just mean that you actually have to write the instance instead of using `deriving`?

Comment: @FUZxxl it appears there is a broken link to the script for deriving `Binary` in the package docs. http://darcs.haskell.org/binary/tools/derive/BinaryDerive.hs :(

Comment: @Alexy Yes.  I was curious if there was a more automatic "deriving" type approach before I went about implementing it by hand.

Comment: deriving binary A) http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/derive/ and B) http://repetae.net/computer/haskell/DrIFT/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link for deriving an instance of `binary` in the documentation is broken as stated in the comments of the question. But the file exists just at a new slightly different URL: http://darcs.haskell.org/packages/binary/tools/derive/BinaryDerive.hs

I haven't used it yet, but I think this does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

A general purpose solution might be to implement `Foldable` and `Unfoldable` (hopefully the latter class exists).